# Characters replaced with replace() turn into 0s

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple program that replaces the characters in a message you enter with the next letter in the alphabet.

```
enalpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
UserInput = input()
x = 0
y = 1
while x < 61:
    UserInput = UserInput.replace(enalpha[x], enalpha[y])
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
print('Encoded Message: ')
print(UserInput)
```

No matter what is entered, the output is always 0s, but is the same number of 0s as the number of characters entered in the `UserInput`.

What I don't understand is when I create a simpler version where user input is not used, the program seems to work fine.

```
enalpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
x = 'hey'
x = x.replace(enalpha[7], enalpha[2])
print(x)
```

And if I change line 7 in the original to `UserInput = 'eggs'` the progrma still spouts out `0000`. There are no error messages. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code changes all `a`'s to `b`'s and all `b`'s to `c`'s including the `a`'s just changed to `b`.  This cycle continues to the very last character, `0`.

If you go through the alphabet backwards or create a second *result* string, you will avoid changing characters more than once.
You could also go through each character (in `userinput`) one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified example:

```
enalpha = "abcdef"
message = "abcdef"
x = 0
y = 1
while x < len(enalpha) - 1:
    message = message.replace(enalpha[x], enalpha[y])
    print(message)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
```

The output:

```
bbcdef
cccdef
ddddef
eeeeef
ffffff
```

As you can see, with each iteration of the loop, more and more letters become the same and are consequently affected by succeeding replace-operations.

Here's one way you might go about doing it:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

# string.digits looks like this: "0123456789"
# to get the desired "1234567890", we slice.
affected_chars = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase + digits[1:] + digits[0]

message = "Hello World 1234567890"
for index, char in enumerate(message):
    if char in affected_chars:
        new_char_index = (affected_chars.find(char) + 1) % len(affected_chars)
        new_char = affected_chars[new_char_index]
        message = message[:index] + new_char + message[index+1:]

print(message)
```

Output:

```
Ifmmp Xpsme 234567890a
```

Notice how the last character "0" in the original message wrapped around our alphabet and turned into "a". That was deliberate on my part, but you can choose to handle 0's differently.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the input message is your current approach will perform 61 replacements while it needs to replace only chars of input message (e.g. `abc` --> `bcd`).
Also, due to the rule *"replace with next letter in the alphabet"* - consider how `0` should be replaced. You may find the rotate variation below.

See the optimized way:

```
enalpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
user_input = input()
res = ''
for c in user_input:
    pos = enalpha.index(c)
    res += enalpha[pos+1] if pos+1 < len(enalpha) else enalpha[0]

print('Encoded Message: ')
print(res)
```

Sample input/output:

```
hello0
Encoded Message: 
ifmmpa
```